# Resource intensive MySQL nested select

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple nested query that is demanding 90+% CPU when it is called, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
SELECT * FROM `push_log` 
WHERE push_id IN 
(SELECT `push_id` FROM push_sent_log 
    WHERE player_id='".$player_id."' 
        OR push_group='All' 
        AND `timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 hour) ) 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC"
```

There are indexes on all the queried fields. Is there a more efficient way for me to do this?

Comment: First of all, please use parentheses when mixing OR and AND queries. Secondly, the root cause of your problem is poor design. You are using the 1:1 relation between `push_log` and `push_sent_log`, which is an anti-pattern PRECISELY because it causes the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

Try remove subquery instead of `join`:

```
SELECT p.*
      FROM push_sent_log ps
      JOIN `push_log` p ON p.push_id= ps.push_id
    WHERE ps.player_id='".$player_id."' 
        OR ps.push_group='All' 
        AND `ps.timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 hour) ) 
    ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC"
```

also I think you need to check `where` in your sql,it seems doesn't make sense due to they are in the same level:

```
 WHERE ps.player_id='".$player_id."' 
            OR ps.push_group='All' 
            AND `ps.timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 hour)  -- why do you using OR and AND at the same time?
```

Comment: That's the ticket! There was a couple of things that I had to correct: Removed ` around `ps.timestamp` and added ( before DATE_SUB.
I tried to edit your answer, but I didn't change enough characters (min of 6).
The reason I have the OR is that the desired select would have the specified push_id , or would the message would have been sent to "all" users, as specified in the push_group column. If you can think of a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Likely pushgroup , player_id and push_id of the table push_sent_log are not included in any index.
The EXPLAIN usually is required to answer this kind of questions.
Can you post What do you get from an explain applied to the nested SQL and to the full SQL?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

In particular note the following statements from the page above:

EXPLAIN works with SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE statements.

When EXPLAIN is used with an explainable statement, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including information about how tables are joined and in which order. For information about using EXPLAIN to obtain execution plan information, see Section 8.8.2, “EXPLAIN Output Format”.

If you have a problem with indexes not being used when you believe that they should be, run ANALYZE TABLE to update table statistics, such as cardinality of keys, that can affect the choices the optimizer makes. See Section 13.7.2.1, “ANALYZE TABLE Syntax”.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Need 50+ rep to comment. For you P. Lion: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  It is not a bad idea to copy the relevant EXPLAIN usage in case the link goes dead some day.

Comment: That is really helpful result for troubleshooting. I appreciate the effort.